# Is there anyway to connect to local SQL Server database from hosted website?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I create a website with a SQL Server database and put it on a host ...

I just want to know if there is a way that when I open my website on a special PC, I could connect to the PC's SQL Server database for reading and writing ...

Let me know if there is a special connection string for that !

Comment: No, there is no *magical* way of connecting to a SQL Server - you just need to specify the server and database in your connection string - no matter where and how you want to connect to it ...

Comment: so.. I couldn't connect local DB ? yeah?

Comment: You need to specify in the connection string the address of the computer serving your database.

Comment: You mean that I need a valid IP for my PC ? yeah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use server IP address and user id , password for connect to database.

Like

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=198.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=Database;user id=user1;password=[system];" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

IP - 198.0.0.1
User id - user1
password - [system]

Note -

1. When you accessing your database from other computer , windows
   authentication will not work.
2. Set sql server authentication in sql server
3. Allow remote connections to sql server
4. Allow Sql server port into firewall

Then try.

Comment: Its very useful for me. Thanks